# How does TensorFlow handle none shape?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a simple computational graph framework and test it with simple neural network, mainly by learning from TensorFlow. Now I would want to be clear how does TensorFlow handle none shape tensors.

In [this example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py), `X` has shape `[None, n_input]`, `weights['h1']` has shape `[n_input, n_hidden_1]`, and `biases['b1']` has shape `[n_hidden_1]`. When it tries to do this: `layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])`, `tf.matmul(x, weights['h1'])` should have shape `[None, n_hidden_1]`, and how exactly does TensorFlow add it with `biases['b1']`? Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add), `tf.add` only works when the 2 operands have the same shape. If we run with a batch of size 10, `tf.matmul(x, weights['h1'])` will have shape `[10, n_hidden_1]`, and it shouldn't be able to be added with `biases['b1']`.

Answer (score 1):

`[None, n_input]` ideally refers as: `None` refers to Batch_size which can be given by us and `n_input` refers to the number of features to be analysed.

So `n_input` refers to 784 pixel data. So we would actual try to do `X.W+b` means `X` (`[None, 784]`) is multiplied by `[784, 256]` the model outputs `[None, 256]` and now comes the addition of bias, here + is also called as broadcasting plus which ideally takes care of adding 256 biases to the 256 hidden cells